# Add a PHP Variable to a JQuery Post passed parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a Jquery post and I want to pass some variable value which I have in php.

Here is the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#button1").submit(function(event) {
         $.post('file.php?do=getLastFile',null,function(attachment){
           //
        },'json');

        });

  </script>
```

I have a php variable ... myPhpVariable which I want to add to:

```
file.php?do=getLastFile
```

so something like this:

```
file.php?do=getLastFile&somevar=$myPhpVariable
```

How can I do the above?

Comment: why are you sending a POST when you're really doing a GET? even your variable is saying so: GETlastfile

Comment: Is this script in a php page, or a js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First assign your php variable to JS and then use that.

```
   var phpvar = '<?php echo $myPhpVariable;?>'; //use it like this
   $("#button1").submit(function(event) {
     $.post('file.php?do=getLastFile&somevar='+phpvar,null,function(attachment){
       //
   },'json');

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Value.php

<?php
   $value = 1;

?>


//This would be the page that would use the value you are trying to pass into jquery
<?php

    include('Value.php');


?>


Usevalue.php page
//Then in your javascript you could collect the variable in the Value.php page
<script>
var value = "<?php echo $value; ?>";

$(document).ready(function (){

   //then you can call the value in your jquery here  
});
</script>
```